# Пропала в Blender кнопка wavefront legacy obj

Tags: blender

Я хотела импортировать объект. Нажимаю импорт, потом ищу нужную мне кнопку , которая раньше точно была. Я раньше пользовалась ноутбуком, вот купила компьютер и кнопка пропала. Очень нужна кнопка wavefront obj (legacy).

Answer (score 0):

Скачайте старую версию приложения, у меня сработало.